# what could be causing elements of my GNOME UI to disappear?

Tags: gnome

I'm not sure what's triggering it, but after a certain amount of time or activity many elements of GNOME seem to disappear on me.  menu items (and some - but not all - other elements) have no text, rounded corners on rectangles are missing, and various other small things render incorrectly.  Please see the attached screenshots for examples.

This behavior occurs:

- on multiple laptops from multiple vendors;
- with GNOME extensions (whatever Ubuntu installs, plus Alternate Tab) enabled or disabled;
- on my laptop's built-in display as well as on an external monitor
- inside VirtualBox as well as on a native install

what are some additional steps I could take to further diagnose this problem?

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 (all packages up-to-date as of this post)

GNOME version: 3.36.3

Windowing System: Wayland

screenshots:

[image]
[image]

thanks!

Comment: This is a rendering problem, I have had similar issues with KDE plasma on debian. Had to use Gnome for a while because of that. I had problems because of OpenGL rendering back-end. Sorry,I don't have any fixes for it.